# Inserting data to list using rest

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I have a list with spaces in its name as `Teams%20List`

```
$.ajax({
        url: parts[0]+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams%20List')/Items",
        type: "POST",
        data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Teams%20ListListItem' }, 
             'Title': data.d.results[k].Title}),
```

and thus the code does not work.

what do I need to do for `'SP.Data.Teams%20ListListItem'` part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove %20 and try it will work

{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TeamsListListItem' }, 
             'Title': data.d.results[k].Title}

If not then

1) Open any browser

2) http://urlsiteurl/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Teams%20List')/?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName

3) Now paste the value of it and try

Comment: Confirmed - this will get you the entity name. It replaces spaces using the normal XML replacement we see in Field names - _x0020_. OP's entity name will be `SP.Data.Teams_x0020_ListListItem`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a space you have to encode it to *x0020* to become "SP.Data.Teams_x0020_ListListItem"

Answer (score 0):

Tried it without %20? `SP.Data.TeamsListListItem`

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try :

JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List'},

Comment: It doesn't work..

Comment: What is the response (header)?